# moment object throws an error 'toDate' is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, momentjs

In reducer I use `moment-timezone` to translate string from API to moment object using only UTC timezone:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
moment.tz.setDefault('UTC');
```

Then I convert the string to moment object:

```
const activeStart = active_start ? moment(active_start) : null;
```

And add it to the store:

```
return { ...state, activeStart };
```

Here everything works great.

Unfortunately, when I get this value from store in container, I'm not able to use [toDate](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method (there is a need of inserting pure JS Date object to one of third part libraries). It says `activeStart.toDate is not a function`. I checked and in reducer I can call `activeStart.toDate()` and it returns proper Date object.

Dependencies:

```
"moment": "2.14.1",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.15",
"react": "^15.6",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
```

I would appreciate any hints, what is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you don't want to store pre-built objects. in Redux as weird things happen. Redux likes to serialize things, and with non-POJO objects (like moment objects) they may get serialized to a point where they still have their data, but lose their functions.

Your best bet is to instead convert it (or leave it) as something that can easily be converted to an object (like a string representation) of the type you need, then in your selector (a function you call to get data out of state), do the conversion there:

```
function getActiveStart(state) {
    return state.activeStart ? moment(state.activeStart) : null;
}
```

Comment: sounds reasonable. Thanks a lot!

Comment:  and there I was thinking I was starting to get the hang of redux!

Answer (score 0):

Mine works when I destructured it.

```
const { name, createdAt } = user

moment(createdAt.toDate()).format()
```